# how to create a constraint on a column, so that it is required to enter a value in the column?

Tags: database, oracle

create a constraint on the product_name column, in the product_information table so that it is required to enter a value in the column. Display all the constraints in the product_information table.

Comment: Just: `product_name not null`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your table is already created then:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY ( column_name NOT NULL);
```

If you are creating the table:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (
    ...
    column_name data_type NOT NULL
    ...
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use `NOT NULL` constraint on column as described in other answers.

To give the answer of the other question which aim to fetch all the constraints of the table, You can use oracle dictionary views as following:

```
Select c.table_name,
       C.constraint_name,
       C.constraint_type,
       Cc.column_name,
       Cc.position,
       C.SEARCH_CONDITION,
       C.r_constraint_name
  From user_constraints c
       Join user_cons_columns
       On c.constraint_name = cc.constraint_name
 Where c.table_name = 'your_table'
Order by c.constraint_name, cc.position;
```

Cheers!!